# GWT DataGrid multi row header

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I am migrating some GWT content from `CellTable` to `DataGrid`, mainly for the DataGrid's feature of locking the header row in place as you scroll.

With CellTable, the column header  text would wrap to the next line if the text phrase was too long. The CellTable's header would dynamically grow in height. This was the default behavior, and I never edited any css files.

Can I get this behavior in DataGrid? Do I need a change to my main project css file, or do I make a change to clean.css? Is there a programatic way to set a proprety on DataGrid?

I am creating `TextColumn`, etc. and adding via `dataGrid.addColumn()`;

Edit: looking at the example here, the header doesn't wrap if you shrink the width of your browser window: http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid

Comment: DataGrid headers wrap the same way. Check in your browser which CSS property prevents them from wrapping (it can be a fixed height, white-space or word-wrap).

Comment: @Andrei, I am not sure how to do that. I know nothing about css. I have the default css that the GWT Eclipse plugin created when creating a new project.

Comment: The showcase DataGrid has `white-space: nowrap;` property set on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
th {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```