# Add header above gwt datagrid column names

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I want to group my datagrid columns by adding some headers above it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

grid.setHeaderSpans(new HeaderSpan("HEADER ONE", new String[] {"field1","field2" }), new HeaderSpan("HEADER TWO", new String[] { "field3","field4"}));  also  visit http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_header_span for detailed info.

Comment: I think that will do it.
But what is SmartGWT? Is that some external library that I need to add it?

Comment: Yes it is. And I think it's overkill if you juste need it for this single problem. Here's the link: https://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/.

Answer (score -1):

Is the question as such: "I want to add a header above my datagrid" ?

If so check use the addColumn(Column, String) as explained [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html)

> A Header can be placed at the top (header) or bottom (footer) of the
>   DataGrid. You can specify a header as text using
>   AbstractCellTable.addColumn(Column, String), or you can create a
>   custom Header that can change with the value of the cells, such as a
>   column total. The Header will be rendered every time the row data
>   changes or the table is redrawn. If you pass the same header instance
>   (==) into adjacent columns, the header will span the columns.

Is making the column sortable also part of the question ?

**EDIT**

Usually you would group header and title in the same row. If you're not satisfied with that, use the above method to set the headers and add a row manually with the column titles, [as this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840997/gwt-datagrid-multi-row-header).

Comment: I think that's not for header. That is for column name.

Comment: The documentation uses the word "header". Maybe we don't understand each other. I see a header as the title above a column. On the first row there is no data, just those column titles. Sometimes you can click on them and sort your data. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I mean something above the column titles so that column titles reside in second row and the values start from third row.